# Proof by induction with polynomials

Tags: polynomials, induction

I need to prove by induction the following equality. I did the inductive hypothesis part, but I don't get it when $n=1$. Any help/ hints are greatly appreciated.

Be $x\neq 1$ and a real number, prove for all $n \in N$
$$\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} +\cdots+ x^2 + x + 1)$$

This is what I've gotten so far:

Assuming this is true for $n$: 
$$\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} +\cdots+ x^2 + x + 1)$$

Then prove it is true for $n+1$

$$\frac{x^{n +1}-1}{x-1} = (x^{n} + x^{n-1} +\cdots+ x^2 + x + 1)$$

Proof:
$$\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} +\cdots+ x^2 + x + 1) \Rightarrow$$
$$x^n-1 = (x-1)  (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} +\cdots+ x^2 + x + 1)$$

And I need to prove that:

$$\begin{align}x^{n+1}-1 &= (x-1)(x^{n} + x^{n-1} +\cdots+ x^2 + x + 1)\\
x^{n+1}-1 &= x\cdot x^n-1\\
&= x\cdot x^n -x^n+ x^n-1\\
&=(x-1)x^n+(x^n-1)
\end{align}$$
Replacing $x^n-1$,
$$=(x-1)x^n+(x-1)(x^{n-1} +\cdots+1)\\
=(x-1)(x^n+x^{n-1} +\cdots+1)$$

And that's proved. But what about $n=1$?
Thanks!

Comment: When $n=1$, then you have that $\frac{x-1}{x-1}=1=x^0=x^{1-1}$, so it holds there.

Comment: OK, thanks, I got it. I got confused thinking it was something greater than 1.