# Prove by induction that for $a\ge1$, $a^{n}-1 = (a-1)(1+a+a^{2}+...+a^{n-1})$, for $n\ge1$, $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.

Tags: inequality, induction, geometric-series

I have doubts about this problem about induction.
The statement says:

> Prove by induction that for $a\ge 1 \Rightarrow$
> $$
> a^n-1 = (a-1)\left(1 + a + a^2 + \ldots + a^{n-1}\right).
> $$
> for $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$

I can see that it is valid for $a=1$ and $n = 1$, but I cannot go on from there.

The associated set is $A = \{2, 3, 4, \ldots \}$, but and the proposition, it's all that or just $a^n -1 = (a-1)\left(1 + a + a^2 + \ldots + a^{n-1}\right)$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Try induction on $n$ (which is a natural number in the claim, whereas $a$ could be a real number)

Comment: $a$ could be any number by the way.

Comment: Even though you should prove this by induction, do you see the result simply by multiplying out the right hand side?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666027/proof-by-induction-with-polynomials).

Comment: For a *rigorous* proof by induction, you would however need to give a *rigorous* definition of the expression in parentheses (i.e., a definition that does not rely on ambiguous notation such as "$\ldots$")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint for the induction step:**

$a^{n+1}-1=a^{n+1}-a^n+a^n-1=(a-1)a^n+(a-1)(1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{n-1})$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$ a^{n+1}-1=a^{n+1}-a+a-1= a\cdot (a^n-1)+(a-1)$$

Comment: your second equality isn't generally correct

Comment: after the edit, it is